# search and replace 1 or more spaces after a period of a files to 2 spaces

Tags: text-processing, sed

Q: What command would you give to print (display on the screen) the corrected text of userNotes.txt with all sentence endings having required two blanks before the start of the next sentence?

here is my code

```
sed 's/.\s/.\s\s/'
```

but this also changed the line where it ended with dot and 2 spaces to dot and 3 spaces.

Comment: Hello @Khang Nguyen. Would you please provide an example?

Comment: Do you mean you want to unify the spaces after the dots? I mean make same space after dots?

Comment: Pelase see my answer and let me know

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing

Comment: (1) "Sentence ending" is different than "a period". There are periods that do not end sentences, and sentences that end without a period. It's quite a complex problem, and even the heuristics of professional typesetting engines like LaTeX often get it wrong.

Comment: (2) Does this SX site have a no-homework policy? A comment on an answer refers to "this assignment", suggesting this is a homework problem.

Comment: This appears to be [a coursework assignment](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs252/latest/Directory/outline/index.html#regular-expressions) from [CS 252 at Old Dominion University](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs252/).  Note that [the Academic Honesty policy](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs252/latest/Public/syllabus/index.html#academic-honesty) is very clear on the subject of submitting other people's work as one's own.  https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4206/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sh
sed 's/\.[[:space:]]\{1,\}/.  /g'
```

Would replace a dot (matched by `\.` or `[.]`, remember `.` matches any character) followed by one or more whitespace characters (`[[:space:]]` being the standard equivalent of `\s`) with `.` followed by two spaces.

You may want to do that for `!` and `?` as well:

```sh
sed 's/\([.!?]\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}/\1  /g'
```

With recent versions of GNU `sed`, you can shorten it to:

```sh
sed -E 's/([.!?])\s+/\1  /g'
```

Or with `perl`:

```sh
perl -lne 's/[.!?]\K\s+/  /g'
```

`[[:space:]]` and `\s` matches any whitespace character (though with `perl` that's limited to the ASCII ones). That includes CR characters though which occur at the end of the lines in MS-DOS text files but are otherwise generally not used as spacing. So those commands may end up breaking MS-DOS line delimiters if applied on MS-DOS formatted files.

Instead of `[[:space:]]`/`\s`, you could use `[[:blank:]]`/`\h` which do not include CR (`\h` is supported by `perl`, but not GNU `sed`).

Comment: the 1st command worked. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your text is saved in a file called 'file', then you an use `awk` as follows

```
cat file
this is OK: Turn the knob. Push the \u201con\u201d button. This is not: Turn the knob. Push the \u201con\u201d button.    

awk '$1=$1' OFS=" " file
```

or `sed` as follows:

```
sed -E "s/[[:space:]]+/ /g" file
```

Comment: sorry but i have to use sed for this assignment

Comment: Ah ok I will update the answer ;-)